# How can I use the new directory structure with Symfony >=2.7?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Before Symfony 2.7 setting the environment variable `SENSIOLABS_ENABLE_NEW_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE` will trigger the prompt *Would you like to use Symfony 3 directory structure?*

Starting from 2.7 (released yesterday) this doesn't work anymore:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition symfony "2.7.*"
```

Any idea why?

<s>I've found a [use-new-directory-structure](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Composer/ScriptHandler.php#L450) shell arg in composer script handler, how do I use it?</s> this is pointless as @zerkms answer.

Using `2.6.*`:

[image]

Using `2.7.*`:

[image]

Comment: Do you see the `Would you like to use Symfony 3 directory structure? [y/N]` invitation actually?

Comment: @zerkms Not anymore when I use "2.7.*". Changing to "2.6.*" and the question appears.

Comment: I can confirm the bug is there; now debugging since I'm curious as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug and after some research I sent a [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/815).

The nature of the bug is the following:

In the [`symfony/symfony-standard@6272b33`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/commit/6272b3388862e57f6fd688f06a1d1c9896fd4ffd) they replaced `PSR-0` composer autoload with `PSR-4` but haven't fixed the path to `SymfonyStandard` directory correspondingly.

This causes the

```
"post-root-package-install": [
    "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
],
```

composer script to not run successfully, since the `SymfonyStandard\\Composer` cannot be resolved.

What that call does is it adds a [handler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app%2FSymfonyStandard%2FComposer.php#L20) for the [`post-root-package-install` event](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events) which in turn sets [couple more event handlers](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app%2FSymfonyStandard%2FRootPackageInstallSubscriber.php#L33) for the `post-install` event.

One of those handlers is the one [`ScriptHandler::defineDirectoryStructure`](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Composer/ScriptHandler.php#L42) which is not invoked at all because of this bug.

Comment: The question is gone with "2.7.*". Same composer, same command but with "2.6.*" and the prompt asks the question about the new directory structure.

Comment: @gremo It's a bug and I sent them a PR